# How to simplify the function and get the omega out of the sqrt[]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How to simplify the function and get the omega out of the sqrt[]?
I give some assumptions and hope that Mathematica can simplify the expression to the result as shown in the figure. Is there any method to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: `Assuming[{w > 0}, w Simplify[ Sqrt[w^2 + w^4/w0^2]  /  w] ]` gives something close.

Comment: Please, post code not pics!

Answer (score 2):

Not the form that you specified, but it does pull an `ω` out of the `Sqrt`

```
expr = Sqrt[ω^2 + ω^4/Subscript[ω, 0]^2]
```

> > [image]

Define a [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

```
cf = (Total[Cases[#, Power[_, n_] :> n, Infinity]^2] + LeafCount[#]) &;

Simplify[expr, {ω > 0, Subscript[ω, 0] > 0},
 ComplexityFunction -> cf]
```

> > [image]